# A model with binomial data?

Tags: spss, binomial-distribution, model

I have a set of data to analyze and I would welcome some ideas.

I have a series of independent observations when a call was produced by individuals. Each observation includes the ID of the caller, and information about other individuals in the vicinity (is there an ally? is there a friend?). There are about 400 of such observations, for about 25 individuals (that is, each of them contributed a certain amount of observations, and not the same amount).

ID Called? Dominants? Friends?
x     yes      yes        no
x      no      no        yes
y     yes      yes       yes

and so on...

I am trying to relate call production to the presence of either dominant or ally presence (or both if they interact), controlling for the ID of the caller.

Given that the dependent variable (call) and the two fixed factors (dominant, friends) have a binomial structure, what could I possibly run to show that one factor in particular predict the presence of a call?

Comment: Have you looked into Logistic Regression?